# Gray code pattern in tournament chart?

Tags: math, design-patterns, gray-code

In a tournament chart from the bottom to the top where there is a winner I've been told that it is somehow connected with the gray-code. I know that the grey code is an alternative code, it's recursive and is useful to find the best solution in various games, space-filling-curves, error correction codes, harddisk positioning and is a shorthand for the piano player but how is this code is related with a tournament chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsed the following from [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/229068):

> A tournament is really a node in a binary tree.  The value in each
>   node contains the ranking of the best ranking team contained in the
>   tournament tree. It turns out that the gray code of the ranking-1 has
>   a bit pattern that conveniently helps us descend the binary tree to
>   the appropriate place at which to put the team. When descending the
>   three, the bits in the gray code of the ranking from least-significant
>   to most-significant indicate which branch to take.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=U-5latje4L4C&lpg=PA5&ots=uyia2kW9B0&dq=gray%20code%20tournament%20%20rankings&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: IMO the gray code can help building a binary tree with only a number and the code? And this binary tree is the same like the tournament chart?